# Unable To Click File Bar Buttons When Running Unity

Tags: command-line, unity

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 in VirtualBox and recently installed Unity as I had read it really helps the latency issues I was experiencing. It helped tremendously, I experience almost no input delay (the original desktop environment was almost rendered unusable). Anyways, I notice that I am unable to click any of the file bar buttons. They show up if I hover up top and they outline if I hover over any of them but when I click, nothing happens. On another note, I am unable to open terminal as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated since I love the unity environment!

Comment: Do you mean shortcut keys Ctrl+Alt+T don't work? Try opening Dash (first icon in Launcher) and typing "Terminal" then selecting it from the list.

Comment: There is no window that opens when trying to open terminal. It shows up in the dock but nothing appears on my screen. And by file bar buttons, I mean in any application that is open, there are associated buttons at the top of the OS. I am unable to click any of these including the basic settings buttons that allow me to log in and out etc

Comment: my Virtualbox VM experience is limited to one installation version 5.1 under Ubuntu 16.04 running Lubuntu 16.04 as a guest OS. Hopefully someone more experience than I answers soon.